# i need to print the list of vehicles that entered on the same date in the parking , user has to enter the date

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my array list:

```
private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList;
    private int numVehicles;
```

And this is where i have to print :

```
public void ListDate(){
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the day month and year");
       System.out.println("Enter the year the vehicle entered the parking");
                int year = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the month the vehicle entered the parking");
                int month = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the day the vehicle entered the parking");
                int day = in.nextInt();
                 DateTime entrytime = new DateTime();
                entrytime.setDay(day);
                entrytime.setMonth(month);
                entrytime.setYear(year);


}
```

i also need to display a message if no vehicles were parked on that date

Comment: Not enough explanation. Could you elaborate what you're problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your purposes (if I've understood your question correctly):

```
class CarPark {
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> _vehicles;

    public CarPark() {
        _vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    }

    public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        _vehicles.add(vehicle);
    }

    public ArrayList<Vehicle> vehiclesForSpecificDate(DateTime: date) {
        ArrayList<Vehicle> filteredVehicles = ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        foreach (Vehicle vehicle in _vehicles) {
            if (vehicle.EntryTime.Day == date.Day) {
                filteredVehicles.add(vehicle);
            }
        }
        return filteredVehicles;
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTime { get; set;}

    public Vehicle(String brand, String model, String registration, DateTime entryTime) {
        Brand = brand;
        Model = model;
        Registation = registration
        EntryTime = entryTime
    }

    override public String toString() {
        return String.Format("The {0} {1} with registration {2} entered the car park at {3}",
                Brand, Model, Registration, EntryTime);
    }
}
```